# priortized search based on property in nested fields elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below as my mapping for some_index.

```
{
  "some_index":
    "properties": {
        "people": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "job": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is boost scores when search query includes properties in people so that the list returned by elastic search such that people with level and job match show on top of the list.

```
"should": [
                {
                    "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                            "terms": {
                                "people": [
                                    {
                                        "level": "l2"
                                        "job": "programmer",

                                    },
                                    {
                                        "level": "l3",
                                        "job": "cs"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "boost": 100
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    } ...
```

This query however don't seem to have any effect at all.
I've tried some other way with match and others, but did not get what I wanted.

Possible alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

DataType of people is "nested". You need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

From question, purpose of  using constant_score was not clear. For nested field your query should be as below.

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "people",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "people.level": {
                            "value": "l2"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "people.job": {
                            "value": "programmer"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "people.level": {
                            "value": "l3"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "people.job": {
                            "value": "cs"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "boost": 1.2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the purpose of constant_score was to boost fields that that match under nested query criterion. I tried your query, but I get [should] query malformed, no start_object after query name"

Comment: @paul.kim1901 query is working fine for me. can you tell your elastic search version. Are you running it after any modification. If yes , please add your query to check.